# Meteor: meteor-collectionapi PUT overwrites the entire object instead of just updating the field I want

Tags: api, mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to use the meteor-collectionapi package to update my database. I've set up a basic collection to test out the functionality.

I'm starting with this data:

```
{ "name" : "Darrell David", "age" : "18", "gender" : "Male", "_id" : "8BW9Yg2oKByBGdnSa" }
{ "name" : "Julie Smith", "age" : "21", "gender" : "Female", "_id" : "fAaFwCEXLzrmejnJK" }
{ "name" : "Todd Davis", "age" : "32", "gender" : "Male", "_id" : "ixKjhkTmjrNte2DjP" }
```

Now, I want to update the gender of the first player to "Female" so I call this using CURL:

```
curl -H "X-Auth-Token: 97f0ad9e24ca5e0408a269748d7fe0a0" -X PUT -d "{\"$set\":{\"gender\":\"Female\"}}" http://localhost:3000/collectionapi/players/8BW9Yg2oKByBGdnSa
```

And what I wind up with is this:

```
{ "_id" : "8BW9Yg2oKByBGdnSa", "" : { "gender" : "Female" } }
{ "name" : "Julie Smith", "age" : "21", "gender" : "Female", "_id" : "fAaFwCEXLzrmejnJK" }
{ "name" : "Todd Davis", "age" : "32", "gender" : "Male", "_id" : "ixKjhkTmjrNte2DjP" }
```

The first player has been completely overwritten and the name and age fields have been lost.

What am I missing here? When I execute this command in the MongoDB console it works perfectly:

```
db.players.update(
   { _id: "8BW9Yg2oKByBGdnSa" },
   { $set: { gender: "Female" } }
)
```

Comment: i assume this is your gh issue? https://github.com/crazytoad/meteor-collectionapi/issues/26 i think you've definitely found a bug, your usage is correct.

Comment: Yes, I created that issue. Drat, I guess that means I either have to wait for a fix or fix it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that bash is replacing "$set" with an empty environment variable

eg. `echo "$set"` vs `echo "\$set"`

so update your PUT command to:

```
curl -H "X-Auth-Token: 97f0ad9e24ca5e0408a269748d7fe0a0" -X PUT -d "{\"\$set\":{\"gender\":\"Female\"}}" http://localhost:3000/collectionapi/players/8BW9Yg2oKByBGdnSa
```

By default Collection.update() will replace a document if no modifiers are present ($set, $unset, $push, $pull etc). So the command being sent to the server is to replace the document with `{"":{"gender":"Female"}}`